# Darktable Switch between RAW and JPEG

Tags: raw, jpeg, darktable, keyboard-shortcuts

I always shoot RAW + JPEG so i see both in darktable conected witch a yellow frame. Is there a shortcut to easy switch between both while editing or even compare them side by side?

best regards
Michael

Comment: Why would this be useful?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there currently (v2.2.5) isn't any such specific feature. It's possible to use the [snapshot](http://www.darktable.org/usermanual/ch03s03s02.html.php) panel across multiple files, though, so you could for instance take a snapshot of a JPEG version, and then view it in split-mode while working on the RAW version.